# In AngularJS, how do I bind a directive into an element other than the directive's root element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want a directive that I'm creating to appear inside an element outside of the scope of the template that the directive appears in.

My issue is that I'm trying to get a lightbox to render over all of the page's content, not just over the content in the template in which it is rendered.

Assuming the structure below, I'd like the `my-directive` directive to run with the scope of `containerController` but I'd like `my-directive`'s template to be rendered into `#lightbox .content`. What's the 'angular' way to accomplish this?

```
<body>
    <div id="container" ng-controller="containerController">
        <my-directive show="directiveVisible"></my-directive>
    </div>

    <div id="lightbox">
        <div class="content"><!-- my-directive template gets rendered here --></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is it you want to achieve ? I'm sure there is a cleaner angularish way to do it !

Comment: I'm trying to get a lightbox to render over all of the page's content, not just over the content in the template in which it is rendered. I updated my answer above to include this.

Comment: Try to have a look at the UI Bootstrap modal source: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for the `$compile` service. You can compile a template (not the template of the directive - leave that empty so that nothing will appear in the place of the directive) and place the compiled element anywhere you like in the DOM. You must also remember to remove the element from the DOM when the scope of the directive is destroyed. So some *very simplistic* code would be:

```
app.directive("myDir", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var target = angular.element(document.getElementById(attrs.target));
            var compiled = $compile('<input type="text" ng-model="data.name" />')(scope);
            target.append(compiled);
            scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
                target.empty();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

A sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3nkp9p9y/

You will notice that the compiled `<input>` appears outside of the directive, in fact outside of the Angular application as well, and still is bound to the controller's scope with prototypical inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If your lightbox is outside of the range of any AngluarJs controller, then you need to reach it via a jQuery like selector (but do that from your controller, not from a directive).
Otherwise, you could just use the `$rootScope` to pass information. `$rootScope` is parent to all scopes.

in the `containerController`, inject `$rootScope` and then :

```
$rootScope.displayTemplate = true; // or false
```

in the controller controlling the lightbox :

```
$scope.displayTemplate = $rootScope.displayTemplate
```

and :

```
<div id="lightbox">
    <div class="content"><div ng-include="yourTemplate" ng-show="displayTemplate"></div></div>
</div>
```